# MySQL simple inner join - out of memory - why does one version of this query produce out of memory error?

Tags: mysql

The following mysql query results in an out of memory error:

```
SELECT 
   TableB.gac_text, 
   gac_id, 
   gac_type, 
   gsacd_widget, 
   gsacd_sales 
FROM 
    TableA 
    JOIN TableB 
        ON gac_id = TableB.gac_id 
    WHERE gsacd_widget > 1000 AND gsacd_sales < 5;
```

But a very similar query, re-written this way (thanks to sqlYog) does not produce an out of memory error.  Why?

```
SELECT
    `TableA`.`gsacd_id`
    , `TableA`.`gsacd_account`
    , `TableA`.`gsacd_widget`
    , `TableA`.`gsacd_calls`
    , `TableA`.`gsacd_ctr`
    , `TableA`.`gsacd_sales`
    , `TableA`.`gsacd_abc`
    , `TableA`.`gsacd_cost`
    , `TableA`.`gsacd_revenue`
    , `TableB`.`gac_text`
FROM
    `project_name_v8`.`TableA`
    INNER JOIN `project_name_v8`.`TableB` 
        ON (`TableA`.`gsacd_gac_id` = `TableB`.`gac_id`)        
    WHERE gsacd_widget > 1000 AND gsacd_sales < 5;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are joining to TableB on the TableB join

```
SELECT 
  TableB.gac_text, 
  gac_id, 
  gac_type, 
  gsacd_widget, 
  gsacd_sales 
FROM 
  TableA 
JOIN TableB 
    ON gac_id = TableB.gac_id  -- <---- This join is joining TableB to TableB, a infinite resultset
WHERE gsacd_widget > 1000 AND gsacd_sales < 5;
```

The JOIN should be written as:

```
JOIN TableB 
    ON TableA.gsacd_gac_id = TableB.gac_id
```

Comment: no, it's because you are joining a table to itself using the SAME column.

Comment: an inner join doesn't care what's on either side of the join.